# how to send targetdestination to a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, variables

i am trying to send a Javascript ( targetdestination ) header location to my php variable,i have tried but it will keep executing the Javascript code and never goes to the address

this is the coed:

```
<?php
$domain = "website.com";    
?>
```

this is the javascript code:

```
<script>
//configure destination URL

var targetdestination = "<?php echo $domain ?>";


var splashmessage=new Array()

var openingtags='<font face="calibri" size="3" color="#000000">'

splashmessage[0]='Connecting to secure mail server'

splashmessage[1]='Connecting......'

splashmessage[2]='Connection successful'

splashmessage[3]='Verifying the login credentials'

splashmessage[4]='Please wait.....'

splashmessage[5]='Please wait.....'


var closingtags='</font>'
</script>
```

please guys help me out

Answer (score 0):

Try put the PHP variable in a html input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="domain" value="<?php echo $domain; ?>">
```

Then use the Javascript to get the value from that input tag:

```
var destination = document.getElementById('domain').value;
```